# Can we use MathJax in comments?

Tags: support, feature-request

Can we write MathJax commands in comments (and in chat)? If not, I believe we should add such a feature...

Comment: tesing... $123$

Comment: Hmm. Works on the regular site.

Comment: MathJax/Latex does not work on the Meta side of this site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, we can use MathJax in comments. You use the regular dollar signs and notation. Be wary, though, of how many dollar signs you use, as choosing the wrong number in a given scenario tends to make the posts harder to read. However, it doesn't seem to work anywhere on meta (note even on questions and answers!).

For chat, see [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/should-chat-have-tex-support/3297#3297).

Comment: MathJax doesn't work anywhere on Meta, not just in the comments.

Comment: By way of explanation, the MathJax script runs _after_ the web page loads. It replaces any sequences of the form `$...$` or `$$...$$` or so on with rendered math; the script doesn't even know whether any such sequence is part of a comment, a post, the sidebar, etc. (code blocks are a special exception)